# Modelling a shift change

Tags: integer-programming, constraints, operations-research, binary-programming

I have the following problem. I am currently modeling shift schedules. There is the variable $x_{itk}$ which tells whether the cashier $i$ completes the shift $k$ on day $t$. Now I want to model the following. I want to introduce a binary variable $l_{it}$ that takes the value 1 if there was a shift change and 0 if not. Here, a shift change is defined as follows. There are three shifts per day, and a cashier must always take a shift, but never more than one. There is an early, day, and late shift. Assume that cashier $i$ has the early shift on day $t$. However, on day $t+1$, he has the day shift. So there was a shift change. The variable $l_{it}$ should therefore take the value 1 on day $t+1$. How can I model this relationship?

I have tried the following so far but I would like it to be a constraint and not a case distinction so I can use it for modeling as well.
$l_{i(t+1)}=\begin{cases}
   1, & \text{if}~x_{it3}+x_{i(t+1)1}+x_{i(t+1)2}=1~~\forall i\in I,~t\in\left| T \right|-1,\\
            0, & \text{else.}
   \end{cases}$

Comment: What is $\ T\ $, and what does "$t\in|T|-1$" mean?         What *set* (of integers) does $|T|-1$ represent?

Comment: $T$ represent the total number of days: $T=\{0,1,.....,28\}. With $|T|-1=\{0,1,....,27\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to enforce the logical implication
$$(x_{i,t,k}\land \lnot x_{i,t+1,k})\implies l_{i,t+1}.$$
You can somewhat automatically derive linear constraints via conjunctive normal form:
$$
\lnot (x_{i,t,k}\land \lnot x_{i,t+1,k})\lor l_{i,t+1}\\
\lnot x_{i,t,k}\lor x_{i,t+1,k}\lor l_{i,t+1}\\
(1- x_{i,t,k})+ x_{i,t+1,k}+ l_{i,t+1}\ge 1 \\
\color{red}{x_{i,t,k} - x_{i,t+1,k} \le l_{i,t+1}}
$$

If shift changes are undesirable (perhaps because of a cardinality constraint or the objective), you can get away without forcing $l_{i,t}=0$ and instead relying on the solver to do so when it is advantageous.  Otherwise, you can again use conjunctive normal form to derive linear constraints that enforce
$$l_{i,t+1}\implies \bigvee_k (x_{i,t,k}\land \lnot x_{i,t+1,k}).$$
Alternatively (because each cashier takes exactly one shift per day), you can enforce
$$(x_{i,t,k}\land x_{i,t+1,k}) \implies \lnot l_{i,t+1},$$
which yields
$$\color{red}{x_{i,t,k} + x_{i,t+1,k} + l_{i,t+1} \le 2}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, two points are still open with me: 1) Assuming $x_{itk}=1$ and $x_{i(t+1)k}=1$, then there was no change and $l_{it}\le 0$. As it should be. If $x_{it1}=1$ and $x_{i(t+1)1}=0$ ,then $l_{it}\le 1$ holds. That also fits. But if $x_{it1}=0$ and $x_{i(t+1)1}=0$ holds, then $l_{it}\le 2$ holds, but actually $l_{it}\le 0$ should hold. How must it be adjusted?

Comment: 2) The constraint captures only one shift change for one shift per day. Doesn't it make more sense to introduce $l_{itk}$ and then $\forall k \in K$. Assuming the problem from 1) can be solved, we can introduce $\sum_{k\in K}^{}l_{itk}=sc_{it}~~~~\forall i\in I$ as a binary variable for the shift change during the day. If the shift from $t$ to $t+1$ remain the same, then $sc_{it}=0$ and if there was a change, then two of the $l_{itk}=1$. So, in addition, the constraint $sc_{it}\le 1~\forall i\in I, t\in T$ is introduced. Would this work?

Comment: If $x_{i,t,1}=x_{i,t+1,1}$, you cannot conclude that $l_{i,t+1}=0$.  It depends on the other two shifts $k\in\{2,3\}$.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate, with concrete values, how exactly these two constraints (case 1) ensure that any change in the shift is captured, regardless of which shift was chosen the day before. Or can I understand it in such a way that the constraints iterates trough all 3 $k$ successively and if for one of the $k$ $l_{it}\ge 1$ applies, then $l_{it}=1$ holds, if it comes however to no change then for all 3 $k$, $l_{it}\ge0$ applies, thus $l_{it}=0$? Did I understand that correctly, if yes, then the constraints hold for $\forall i\in I, t\in \{2,...,T\}, k\in K$, correct?

Comment: If $x_{i,t,k}=1$ and $x_{i,t+1,k}=0$ for some $k$, then the first constraint forces $1-0\le l_{i,t+1}$, hence $l_{i,t+1}=1$.  If $x_{i,t,k}=1$ and $x_{i,t+1,k}=1$ for some $k$, then the second constraint forces $1+1+l_{i,t+1}\le2$, hence $l_{i,t+1}=0$.  Regarding the indexing, the constraints apply for $i\in I, t\in\{1,\dots,T-1\}, k\in K$.

Comment: Thanks. Would this formulation also work? $\begin{align}
  & x_{itk}+\sum_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq k}}^{3}x_{i(t+1)j}\le 1+l_{i(t+1)}, \forall i\in I, k\in K,t\in\left\{1,...,T-1  \right\} 
\end{align}$

Comment: Yes, that is equivalent to my first red constraint because $\sum_j x_{i,t+1,j}=1$.

Comment: Thanks. One last question. Assuming I also introduced a binary variable $\omega$ which indicates whether a shift was worked at least once the two days prior, it also introduces shifts off. $\omega=1$ if he didnt and $\omega=0$ if he worked at least once. How can i add this to my constraint presented or which additional constraint do i need? So the constraint(s) should do the following, so to speak. 1) First, $l_{it}=1$ if the worker is not working on $t$ so, $y_{it}=0$ holds.

Comment: 2) If $\omega=1$, then that means that neither in $t-1$ nor in $t-2$ was worked, which means automatically that in $t-3$ was worked. So if $\omega=1$ is valid, then the period $t-3$ should be compared to see if there was a shift change. 3) If $\omega=0$, then the person must have worked in $t-1$, insofar as case 1) does not occur, since the break is exactly 2 days. Then the reference period for the change should be $t-1$ as already modeled so far. Would be helpful if you could still help me here.

Comment: Please open a new question for your new question.

Comment: Thank you. I will come back to your answer. If I understand it correctly, then the constraint creates a lower bound or? So if there was a change then the indicator is forced to 1, but if not then the indicator can take 0 or 1. How can I introduce an additional constraint that defines such an upper bound?

Comment: The second constraint in red does what you are asking.

Answer (score -1):

Try
$ x_{i,t,k} - x_{i,t+1,k} \le l_{i,t} \le 2- x_{i,t,k} - x_{i,t+1,k}$
$ x_{i,t+1,k} - x_{i,t,k} \le l_{i,t}$
$l_{i,t} \le x_{i,t,k} + x_{i,t+1,k} $

Comment: One thing is still not quite clear to me. If $x_{itk}=1$ and $x_{it+1k}=1$ is true, then $0\ge l_{it}\le 0$. As it should be. However, if $x_{itk}=0$ and $x_{it+1k}=$, then $0\ge l_{it}\le becomes 2$, but it should be $0\ge l_{it}\le 0$ as above, since the shift has not changed. Do you also have an answer regarding 2) below @RobPratt post?

Comment: @manofthousandnames Add one more
$l_{i,t} \le x_{i,t,k} + x_{i,t+1,k} $

Comment: Your third constraint is not valid.  You can correct it by summing the RHS over $k$, but that would then be redundant because the sum is $2$.